# Prevent jquery slimscroll bar from overlaying absolute positioned div beneath on zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I ran into a problem while developing a section of my website.

I have a column with a jquery slimscroll in it, and a div (.footer) absolute positioned on the bottom. It HAS to be on the bottom, because I want it to be there even if the user zooms the page.
The column is positoned in relation to the top, this is neccessary because of the design.
Is there a way only with CSS to prevent the slimScroll from flowing in to the footer? Or do I have to use a special JQuery code? How should I make it?

Basically, I want the SlimScroll div to fill the .container div as long as it is not overlapping the .footer.

Fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sgshbw7g/14/)

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasda </div>
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasdasd </div>
        <div class="message"> asdasd</div>
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message">asdasd </div>
        <div class="message"> asdasd</div>
        <div class="message">asdasdasd </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.Wrapper {
position:relative;
height:90vh;
background-color:gray;
width: 300px;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:50px; }

.container {
width:300px;
height:70vh;
background-color:lightgray; }

.content {
max-width:300px;
height:70vh;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden; }

.message {
border: 2px solid red;
height: 80px;
width:296px; }

.footer {
position:absolute;
background-color:cyan;
width:300px;
height:100px;
bottom:0px; }
```

The JQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('.content').slimScroll({
    height: '450px'
});
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `height : 'Auto';`

Change your function as below.

```
$(function(){
    $('.content').slimScroll({
        height: 'auto'
    });
});
```

You may need to set some padding along with this.

Comment: Same thing happens, when you zoom in you can see the slimscroll bar in the footer div.